DB scripts deployment via Azure DevOps Pipeline
I am getting below error while trying to build db scripts via Azure DevOps Pipeline.

##[error]No agent found in pool Default which satisfies the specified demands: msbuild, visualstudio, Agent.Version -gtVersion 2.182.1

screenshots for reference.


Please help.

When using self-hosted build agents ensure that the agents are up-to-date and Visual Studio is installed in the agent.
If msbuild and visualstudio demands are not added automatically after Visual Studio installation you can add them manually.
As an alternative consider using the Microsoft-hosted agents (select windows-latest as your default build pool).

I am not authorized to do so, maybe because the client side did not opt for this functionality.
There was a resource authorization issue: "The pipeline is not valid. Could not find a pool with name Azure Pipelines. The pool does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz."
